# How to measure WebSockets and WebService latency

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, webforms, websocket

I have two applications Web Socket and Web Service created in .Net/Web Form and running locally
Is there any online tool or is there any simple code that I can measure the latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dev tools in chrome has some timing/logging functionnalities which may be sufficient?

Comment: how to find that functionnalities on Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: Maybe with Yslow extension? check extension gallery (http://extensions.apple.com/), i'm not a Mac user i don't really know safari

Comment: "how to find that functionnalities on Chrome Dev tools?" - The chrome dev tool is more for traffic inspection than for profiling... But here are the steps with video how to do it: http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/